Running an SQL script on demand and showing the results as a table in a published Power BI report
I have a large dataset in a SQL database. I want the user to enter a search string which will then execute an SQL  query to pull relevant data that will then show up as a table in the report. I cant define the query in the source of the power query table since it will take a long time for the report to refresh.
Is there a way to have Power BI execute the query with the search string as a filter and show the report?

You will need to look at using DirectQuery

Paginated reports would be the way to go for this maybe?

@SamNseir The query im using is a recursive query that uses a WITH clause. DirectQuery does not allow WITH clauses
